# Running Another TestCases, looping through Properties (getValues &SetValues) - Groovy Script

Tags: rest, groovy, soap, soapui

how can I get all of the properties (it shouldn’t matter if there are only 2 or 100 on the list) with values from TestStep “LIST” from TestCase S_TC_Addition and set them on the TestStep “LIST” in TestCase M_TC_Add, and then, get all properties and values from TestStep “EXIT” in TestCase M_TC_Add and set them on the TestStep “EXIT” in TestCase S_TC_Addition, in groovy script (in this case EXECUTION_Addition)?

At the moment I have this (which only gets and sets properties that I've manually indicated "FirstValue", "SecondValue"):

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.*
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.*
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.*

//Locating TestCase in different project
def projectName = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("TRACING_TC_Addition").getPropertyValue("PROJECT_NAME")
def testSuitetName = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("TRACING_TC_Addition").getPropertyValue("TEST_SUITE_NAME")
def testCaseName = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("TRACING_TC_Addition").getPropertyValue("TEST_CASE_NAME")

//Getting only two properties from the "LIST" TestStep in S_TC_Addition TestCase
def firstNumber = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("LIST").getPropertyValue("FirstValue")
def secondNumber = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("LIST").getPropertyValue("SecondValue");

//Setting only two properties on the "LIST" TestStep in M_TC_Add TestCase
def passFirst = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.getProjectByName(projectName).getTestSuiteByName(testSuitetName).getTestCaseByName(testCaseName).getTestStepByName("LIST").setPropertyValue("FirstValue", firstNumber);
def passSecond = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.getProjectByName(projectName).getTestSuiteByName(testSuitetName).getTestCaseByName(testCaseName).getTestStepByName("LIST").setPropertyValue("SecondValue", secondNumber);

//Running TestCase in different project
testCaseToRun = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.getProjectByName(projectName).testSuites[testSuitetName].testCases[testCaseName]
testCaseToRun.run(null,false)

//Getting one property from the "EXIT" TestStep in M_TC_Add TestCase
def getAdditionResult = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.getProjectByName(projectName).getTestSuiteByName(testSuitetName).getTestCaseByName(testCaseName).getTestStepByName("EXIT").getPropertyValue("additionResult");

//Setting only one property on the "EXIT" TestStep in S_TC_Addition TestCase
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["EXIT"].setPropertyValue( "additionResult", getAdditionResult);
```

[image: Scheme]

Comment: So many words... Where is the question?

Comment: @daggett The question is how can I get all properties with values (from testStep LIST) from one testCase (S_TC_Addition) and set them on the LIST in another testCase (M_TC_Add) using groovy script

Comment: Please edit the question and put this information there. So, it'll be clear for everyone.

Comment: @daggett Hope it's more understandable now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking for properties/methods of some object, then always use something like :

`println (obj.getClass())`

in your case `println( testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("TRACING_TC_Addition").getClass() )`

this will give you the name of class you are working with

then search `javadoc your.class.name` over the internet and it should give you the reference like this:

https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/5.5.0/com/eviware/soapui/model/TestPropertyHolder.html

---

for your case you could get all properties for a test step:

```
List props = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("TRACING_TC_Addition").getPropertyList()

props.each{ p->
    println( "${p.getName()} = ${p.getValue()}" )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what I was trying to achieve :) Thanks to daggett :)

```
//Get all properties from current TestCase's TestStep "LIST" and transfer them to indicated TestCase in code above, and set them in TestStep "LIST"
def ListProperties = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("LIST").getPropertyList()
ListProperties.each{ lp->
    passPropertiesToList = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.getProjectByName(projectName).getTestSuiteByName(testSuitetName).getTestCaseByName(testCaseName).getTestStepByName("LIST").setPropertyValue("${lp.getName()}", "${lp.getValue()}");
}

//Get all properties from current TestCase and transfer them to indicated TestCase in code above
def exitProperties = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.getProjectByName(projectName).getTestSuiteByName(testSuitetName).getTestCaseByName(testCaseName).getTestStepByName("EXIT").getPropertyList()
exitProperties.each{ ep->
    passPropertiesToExit =  testRunner.testCase.testSteps["EXIT"].setPropertyValue("${ep.getName()}", "${ep.getValue()}");
}
```